# adjusting the scale of a barplot and merging data of a type into a single bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

First of all... I'm sorry about my Enlgish.. I am probably lacking the most fitting term every now and then...

Anyways.. I want to make a Barplot, with multiple bars displayed underneath each other (so flip the Barplot to the side).

The data that I have could look somewhat like this:

```
t1 = c('name1','name1','name2','name2')
t2 = c(5,0,2,1)
t3 = c('a','b','a','b')
test = data.frame(cbind(t1, t2, t3))
```

In t1, we have names,

in t2 we have values,

in t3 we have the type.. Kind of like a superset. It either belongs to type a or type b.

Ideally, I would like to display the dataobject with the same name (t1), yet different types (t3) in the same row/bar or in directly adjacent bars. (This seems to work)

Also, the colourdistinction between the two types works.

```
ggplot(test, aes(x = t1, y = t2, fill = t3)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge()) +
    geom_text(aes(label=t2), color = 'white') + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Paired') + 
    theme_minimal() +
    coord_flip()
```

Now my issues/questions:

What unfortunately does not work is the scale of the barplot. On the x-Axis you see the values 0,1,2,5 which are displayed having an equal distance between them.. But 5 is obviously further away from 2 than 1 is from 2.

How can I fix the scaling issue?
Thus far, it has not worked with setting xmin oder xlim(,), or the same with y. Also, factoring the values did not work, just like ordering or so didn't.

Also.. the display of the numbers, which I would like to have directly attached to the Bar, looks super weird. The number is hidden at the intersection of the two bars.

How could I fix this?

Thank you very much for your help, and I dearly hope, that my explanation made some sense.

Answer (score 1):

Actually when you are using `cbind` the `t2` is becoming factor. You can use `cbind.data.frame` function like

```
test = cbind.data.frame(t1, t2, t3)
str(test)

'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ t1: Factor w/ 2 levels "name1","name2": 1 1 2 2
 $ t2: num  5 0 2 1
 $ t3: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 2 1 2

ggplot(test, aes(x = t1, y = t2, fill = t3)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_text(aes(label=t2), color = 'white') + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Paired') + 
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_flip()
```

See the `str` of your data

```
t1 = c('name1','name1','name2','name2')
t2 = c(5,0,2,1)
t3 = c('a','b','a','b')
test = data.frame(cbind(t1, t2, t3))
str(test)

'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ t1: Factor w/ 2 levels "name1","name2": 1 1 2 2
 $ t2: Factor w/ 4 levels "0","1","2","5": 4 1 3 2
 $ t3: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 2 1 2
```

For `geom_text` positioning

```
ggplot(test, aes(x = t1, y = t2, fill = t3)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_text(aes(label=t2), color = 'black', 
            position = position_dodge(width = 1), hjust = -0.5) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Paired') + 
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Or even more simple, just `data.frame(t1, t, t3)`. Also, to have the text in white, `geom_label` will put a box around the text making it more visible.